# How to search for a word in a single column, but not the whole table using datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to write a code which will search for a word (say- 'party') in the third column of a table using 'datatable.js' plugin. The search box is at the head of the table and for the search box(input type = text) the id is 'primaryName'. I wrote the following code-

```
var Table = $('#abc').dataTable({"bPaginate": false,
                     "bLengthChange": false,
                     "bSort" : false,
                     // bInfo: false
                     // move the location of the search box.
                     "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                         $('#primaryName').children(0).appendTo($('#termsResources').children(0));
                    }});
$('#primaryName').on( 'keyup', function () {
    Table.columns( 3 ).search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

But this is still searching for a word given in the search box in the whole table.

Comment: where does `cdtTable` come from?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected that now

Comment: well according to the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) it should be `table.column(3).search( this.value).draw();`

Comment: I tried that but still did not work. I am editing the main post as well.